# apache2 localhost refused to connect

Tags: server, apache2, chef

I'm installing apache2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 with a custom cookbook in Chef.  I cannot connect to localhost after a fresh converge, and I'm not having Chef modify any configuration files until I figure out why I cannot connect.  I expect to see the default index.html landing page, but nothing works.  I can ssh into my vagrant machine, but my browser will not load anything from the server.  By the end of this I would like to have my own HTML file that I had Chef build in `/var/www/html/` act as the landing page for my Apache server.

Below are a few methods I have already attempted:

I have ran `wget localhost` and 127.0.0.1 always outputs:

```
--2017-06-21 08:40:05--  http://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

Running `sudo systemctl status apache2` in my VM outputs:

```
Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-06-21 12:17:31 UTC; 31min ago
```

Running `ps -ef | grep apache` in my VM outputs:

```
root     12881     1  0 12:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12884 12881  0 12:17 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12885 12881  0 12:17 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
vagrant  13125 13109  0 13:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

Running `netstat -a | grep less` in my VM returns:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:ssh           10.0.2.2:40222          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN 
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
```

I have previously attempted to modify the config files in

- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

Lastly, I have checked permissions on `/var/www` and `/var/www/html`, and they're all `0755`

All the above have lacked any form of success.  Please help.  Before you ask, yes I did restart the apache process after every modification to the server.

Comment: There's a `Listen` directive in your Apache configuration files. What does it say? My guess is, that Apache is listening to IPv6 only. What's your output of `sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only`?

Comment: `sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only` returns `net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0`

Comment: My `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` contains `Listen 80`

Also, I apologize in advance.  I absolutely hate the markdown in this site.

Comment: This q was silent for quite some time, so I guess the problem was resolved. Thinking further about useful diagnostic steps, it would be of interest, if `iptables` is blocking something.